# How do I turn off the gutter icons in the IntelliJ IDEA editor?

Tags: editor, intellij-idea

I want the implementing and override gutter icons turned off in the gutter (next to the line numbers). Their rendering is causing my editor window to jump every time they redraw (with each keystroke I type), and it is driving me nuts. I'm using version 8.1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been [fixed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-50006) in 9.x versions. You can't disable gutter icons in IDEA.

Comment: Do you know if there is a fix for 8? I didn't see it in that bug. I can't upgrade for free to 9.

Comment: There is no fix for 8.x, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

### IntelliJ IDEA 2017

#### Approach 1

**File** > **Settings...** > **Editor** > **General** > **Gutter Icons** > uncheck **Show gutter icons**

[image: File > Settings > Editor > General > Gutter Icons]

#### Approach 2

**Help** > **Find Action...** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) > type "Show Gutter" and switch the toggle using <kbd>Enter</kbd> or mouse left click.

[image: Show Gutter]